# Spring Boot auto reconfiguration not working on spring-boot-data-starter-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-jdbc

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to CF connecting a Postgres backing service . I can see the db properties are not being replaced in run time with VCAP env.
I am using the dependency - spring-boot-starter-jdbc ( not spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as i intend to use JDBC template and not JPA).

Steps

Added the following jars in pom.xml ( spring-boot-starter-data-jpa , postgresql- driver)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Create a bean returning the type DataSource

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    return builder.build();
}
```

Specify connection properties in application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username= dummy
spring.datasource.password=dummy
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
```

With this the local setup works fine . When the application is deployed to Cloud foundry the expectation is spring auto reconfiguration should replace the bean with properties in vcap .
However the values dont seem to be replaced and system tries to connect to localhost on CF which fails.

I have reviewed all the documents and they seem to work with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa but not with jdbc. I can see the auto reconfig not working in case of JDBC scenario.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Veera

Comment: Isnt the property ```spring.datasource.url``` is this?

Comment: I had tried with spring.datasource.url as well and it had not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you avoid using auto reconfiguration. It's cool for a demo, but it ends up being difficult to use in earnest. It's a bit too magical and it's difficult to debug when it doesn't work, which is what you're running into here.

There's a couple other ways you can do this:

- Spring Boot exposes `VCAP_SERVICES` as properties like `vcap.services.<name>.credentials.username`. You could use those to manually define a DataSource. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html). Combining this with with the "cloud" profile makes it easy to switch between local & cloud.
- You can [use Spring Cloud Connectors](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server). The auto reconfiguration will automatically back off when you're using SCC. You can then use SCC to pick out a service & get a DataSource from it.
- You can use the new [java-cfenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv#introduction) library, which is [intended to complement Spring Boot better](https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/15/introducing-java-cfenv-a-new-library-for-accessing-cloud-foundry-services).

Comment: Also see the comment on your issue here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration/issues/71#issuecomment-501714203. Mixing Spring Boot autoconfiguration via properties and Java Buildpack auto-reconfiguration isn't going to do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the answer. I contemplated use of spring cloud connector but i wanted to keep implementation simple with respect to testing locally and testing in cloud.
Existing Implementation
No data source bean is present in code.
Maintain the db params in application.properties(jdbc url, user, password)
Works well locally. While running in cloud foundry, auto reconfiguration automatically overrides the property and connection to cloud db works.

Comment: With Spring cloud connector , i believe i need to create a Data source bean. How will properties of db (url,user,password) be used to instantiate database connection? 
How can i ensure the code works locally and on cloud without checks in code like mode==cloud or mode==local?

Comment: @Veeraraghavan what you're looking for is profiles: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment. The recommended approach is to set the `spring.datasource...` properties directly in a "local" profile, and include the `java-cfenv` lib that Daniel mentioned above to get those properties set automatically when running on CF.